# Why pytest calls a duplicate method

Tags: python, pytest, self

why does this happen?
duplicate call because I added "self.log"

code

```
import logging, logging.handlers
class TestCase:

    def setup_method(self,test_method):
            self.log = logging.getLogger('test')
            self.log.addHandler( logging.StreamHandler())

    def test_one(self):
            log = self.log
            log.info('one')
    def test_two(self):
            log = self.log
            log.info('two')
```

console out

```
$pytest -s
=========================================== test session starts ===========================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.2, pytest-3.3.1, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /Users/taeun/dev/workspace/test/pytest-test/tests, inifile:
collected 2 items

test_one.py one
.two
two
.                                                                                      [100%]
```

anyone help me?

Comment: Please paste your source code as text, not images.

Comment: I update it just before! thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are adding a `StreamHandler` to your logger in the `setup_method`, [which will be called once for each test run](https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.7.3/xunit_setup.html#method-and-function-level-setup-teardown). What happens if you run both tests:

1. `setup_method` is called, one instance of `StreamHandler` is added to the logger
2. `test_one` runs, the logger has one handler that send the message `one` to stdout
3. `setup_method` is called for the second time, adding **another instance** of `StreamHandler` to the logger handlers
4. `test_two` runs, but now the logger has two handlers, both sending the message `two` to stdout

To overcome this, you can either clean up handlers in the `setup_method` to ensure you have one `StreamHandler` on each test run:

```
class TestCase:

    def setup_method(self):
        self.log = logging.getLogger('test')
        self.log.handlers = [h for h in self.log.handlers
                             if not isinstance(h, logging.StreamHandler)]
        self.log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

        ...
```

or you declare the logger configuration as a one-time operation (a much cleaner solution if you ask me):

```
class TestCase:

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        logging.getLogger('test').addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

    def setup_method(self,test_method):
        self.log = logging.getLogger('test')

    ...
```

Comment: Oh my god... really thank you for your kindly answers(_ _)

Comment: @taeun glad if I could help you! Try the code out, if your question will be resolved, you may consider to accept the answer...